# How to customize the Lubuntu menu? Where is the .xml file responsible for it?

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, customization

I know that the menu can be modified editing the .xml file responsible for it, but I've did a research on the web and nothing helped me find this file. So I'm here asking, how to customize the Lubuntu menu? Where is the .xml file responsible for it?

This is the Lubuntu menu: (the image is just to illustrate the question, as I could not find a screenshot of Lubuntu 12.10 menu)

[image]